# Why does Salsa20 algorithm require incrementing word[8] and word[9] after producing cipher text message

Tags: salsa20, algorithm-design

I'm trying to get understanding of Salsa20 algorithm. There is an official specification from Daniel J. Bernstein at [link](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/spec.pdf). Everything in spec is clear and I could write an implementation on Swift.

But I met Salsa20 cipher algorithm implemented by other developers [Crypto and TLS for C++11](https://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/salsa20_8cpp_source.html) , [Salsa20 written on Python](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.857/2016/files/salsa20.py)
The developers perform some operations with words at positions **8** and **9** after generating ciphertext message:
[image]

I didn't saw these operations in the [original Salsa20 spec](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/spec.pdf). What do these increments mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code only increments word 9 when word 8 is zero. Just like when counting you increment the next digit whenever the previous digit is zero, going from 9 to 10.

This is equivalent to having a 64-bit counter and putting the lower half into word 8 and the upper half into word 9.

Comment: I understand the code, but I’m not clear why it was added for?

Comment: @IgorKotkovets Salsa20 is Salsa20 core in CTR mode. So you need a counter. The spec says the counter is 64 bits, divided into two 32-bit words.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Reading the PDF spec, the $Salsa20_k(n)$ expansion function defines a single 16 byte input $n$, then section 10 references that function called with 2 distinct inputs, the 8 byte nonce $v$ and "the unique 8 byte sequence" $i$. It should have used a concatenation symbol instead of a comma, took me a few minutes to figure out what was supposed to happen.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, you are right. It's Salsa20 in CTR mode. There is no mentions about CRT mode in the original Salsa20 spec. Probably it's common convention to use word 8,9 for a counter.

Comment: @IgorKotkovets It's a bit implicit in the paper. It defines a function with a 16 byte nonce parameter and then defines a function which passes an 8 byte nonce and an 8 byte counter as that argument (as Richie Frame commented). The NaCl paper is a bit clearer. Salsa20 is Salsa20Core in counter-mode.